# Can .NET 6.0 be installed on Windows 2012 R2?

Tags: .net, windows

Does .NET 6.0 work with Windows 2012 r2? I could not find any system requirements on the site: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes .net 6.0 is supported on Windows Server 2012r2. Microsoft documented it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net60).

Comment: Overall system support can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/supported-os.md